# Rails scope that does nothing for NOT IN values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

I have a Rails 3 scope that excludes an array of ids.

What is the best way to write the scope so that it does nothing when the array is empty and is still chainable? I currently have this, which works, but seems a little hokey:

```
scope :excluding_ids, 
         lambda {|ids| ids.empty? ? relation : where('id not in (?)', ids) }
```

If I do not have the "ids.empty? ? relation :" bit, when ids is empty the SQL generated is

```
... ID not in (NULL) ...
```

which will always return nothing. So something like:

```
Model.excluding_ids([]).where('id > 0')
```

returns no results.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the `ids` array is empty then don't return anything.

```
scope :excluding_ids, lambda { |ids|
  where(['id NOT IN (?)', ids]) if ids.any?
}
```

The query will run without any additional constraints on the query if there are no `ids`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. (deleted my prior comment that had an error since I can't edit it now)

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 4 you can use:

```
scope :excluding_ids, ->(ids) { where.not(id: ids) }
```

Comment: Don't you mean "... ->(ids) { where.not(id: ids) }"? See: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slight variation on Douglas' answer, using ruby 1.9 stabby lambda syntax and without the brackets in the where method.

```
scope :excluding_ids, ->(ids) {where("id NOT IN (?)", ids) if ids.any?}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following? (It still checks for an empty array though, so if that's what you're trying to avoid it's not much of an improvement :)

```
scope :excluding_ids,
     lambda {|ids| (ids.empty? && relation) || where('id not in (?)', ids) }
```