# How to make a Rails 3 Dynamic Scope Conditional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to make a dynamic named scope in rails 3 conditional on the arguments passed in. For example:

```
class Message < AR::Base
  scope :by_users, lambda {|user_ids| where(:user_id => user_ids) }
end

Message.by_users(user_ids)
```

However, I'd like to be able to call this scope even with an empty array of user_ids, and in that case not apply the where. The reason I want to do this inside the scope is I'm going to be chaining several of these together.

How do I make this work?

Comment: This is very similar & is also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519293/rails-3-scope-that-does-nothing-for-not-in-values

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To answer your question you can do:

```
scope :by_users, lambda {|user_ids| 
  where(:user_id => user_ids) unless user_ids.empty?
}
```

**However**

I normally just use `scope` for simple operations(for readability and maintainability), anything after that and I just use class methods, so something like:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.by_users(users_id)
    if user_ids.empty?
      scoped
    else
      where(:user_id => users_id)
    end
  end

end
```

This will work in Rails 3 because `where` actually returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, in which you can chain more queries.

I'm also using [`#scoped`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scoped), which will return an anonymous scope, which will allow you to chain queries.

In the end, it is up to you. I'm just giving you options.

Comment: Returning #scoped is what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was doubtful whether scoped was the right thing to return here. The docs say it returns "an anonymous scope". But in this case we want it to return "the current scope with no additional methods applied". In fact it does work as you suggested, i.e. if I call Message.where(text: "XY").by_users(nil) the first where is still applied.

Comment: FYI: in Rails 4, `scoped` has been deprecated, you should use `all` instead.