# rails "where" statement: How do i ignore blank params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, where-clause

I am pretty new to Rails and I have a feeling I'm approaching this from the wrong angle but here it goes... I have a list page that displays vehicles and i am trying to add filter functionality where the user can filter the results by vehicle_size, manufacturer and/or payment_options.

Using three select form fields the user can set the values of :vehicle_size, :manufacturer and/or :payment_options parameters and submit these values to the controller where i'm using a

```
@vehicles = Vehicle.order("vehicles.id ASC").where(:visible => true, :vehicle_size => params[:vehicle_size] )
```

kind of query. this works fine for individual params (the above returns results for the correct vehicle size) but I want to be able to pass in all 3 params without getting no results if one of the parameters is left blank..

Is there a way of doing this without going through the process of writing if statements that define different where statements depending on what params are set? This could become very tedious if I add more filter options.. perhaps some sort of inline if has_key solution to the effect of:

```
@vehicles = Vehicle.order("vehicles.id ASC").where(:visible => true, if(params.has_key?(:vehicle_size):vehicle_size => params[:vehicle_size], end if(params.has_key?(:manufacturer):manufacturer => params[:manufacturer] end )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
@vehicles = Vehicle.order('vehicles.id ASC')
if params[:vehicle_size].present?
  @vehicles = @vehicles.where(vehicle_size: params[:vehicle_size])
end
```

Or, you can create scope in your model:

```
scope :vehicle_size, ->(vehicle_size) { where(vehicle_size: vehicle_size) if vehicle_size.present? }
```

Or, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748550/how-to-make-a-rails-3-dynamic-scope-conditional) answer, you can create class method:

```
def self.vehicle_size(vehicle_size)
  if vehicle_size.present?
    where(vehicle_size: vehicle_size)
  else
    scoped # `all` if you use Rails 4
  end
end
```

You call both scope and class method in your controller with, for example:

```
@vehicles = Vehicle.order('vehicles.id ASC').vehicle_size(params[:vehicle_size])
```

You can do same thing with remaining parameters respectively.

Comment: Ahh - so you set @vehicles and then you put it through a where statement for each filter that is present?.. I was envisioning doing it all in one line but this works fine - thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The [has_scope gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) applies scope methods to your search queries, and by default it ignores when parameters are empty, it might be worth checking